# Scrapy cannot find Django app settings

Tags: django, scrapy

> **My localhost is worked, but production host cannot.Who can help me this?**

```
File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(execute())
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
settings = get_project_settings()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 292, in setmodule
module = import_module(module)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/project-1.0-py2.7.egg/Crawler/settings.py", line 20, in <module>
application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Dashboard.settings.
```

Dashboard is a django project

Comment: Solution: 
 remove the old egg